# Django Webpack Loader Breaking Vue Router Links

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack

**Short Version**
When I visit `localhost` my django/vue app renders fine. But when I click into a link, rather than being brought to `localhost/about` I'm brought to `http://localhost/http:/0.0.0.0:8080/about` because of my webpack and `vue.config.js` settings.

**Details**
I have an application running (in docker-compose) Django on the backend and Vue on the frontend. The app uses django-webpack-loader and `webpack-bundle-tracker` to render the application in Django.

```
# Django settings.py
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    "DEFAULT": {
        "CACHE": DEBUG,
        "BUNDLE_DIR_NAME": "/bundles/",
        "STATS_FILE": os.path.join(FRONTEND_DIR, "webpack-stats.json"),
    }
}
```

```
# Django urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    re_path("^.*$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="application.html"), name="app"),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = (
        urlpatterns
        + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
        + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    )
```

```
<!-- Template -->
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but this application doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
        <div id="app">
             <app></app>
         </div>{% render_bundle 'app' %}<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// vue.config.js
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
  publicPath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? "https://example.com"
      : "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
  outputDir: "./dist/",

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.splitChunks(false);

    config
      .plugin("BundleTracker")
      .use(BundleTracker, [{ filename: "webpack-stats.json" }]);

    config.resolve.alias.set("__STATIC__", "static");

    config.devServer
      .public("http://0.0.0.0:8080")
      .host("0.0.0.0")
      .port(8080)
      .hotOnly(true)
      .watchOptions({ poll: 500 })
      .https(false)
      .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] });
  }
};
```

When I fire up the application, visiting `localhost` works fine, but if I try to click one of the vuetify links, it brings me to `http://localhost/http:/0.0.0.0:8080/about` (presumably because that's the URL I've specified as the publicPath for the dev environment). If I replace localhost with `http://0.0.0.0` I get the same undesired redirection to http://0.0.0.0/http:/0.0.0.0:8080/. However, if I visit `localhost:8080` I can browse the app and links click through to their proper location (eg localhost:8080/about).

I tried removing my configuration of the `publicPath` but the Django application is unable to serve up the vue app when I do so: the app loads a blank page with a javascript error of `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` in app.js. I assume that's because it's trying to load `http://0.0.0.0/app.js` and receiving the same template response that `http://0.0.0.0` serves up.

So I think I have a few options:
1) Should I keep the default `vue.config.js` `publicPath` option, and configure django to serve up `app.js` from the proper location (and if so, what is that location?)
2) Can I configure vue router to use a different root URL from that specified in `publicPath`?

If this configuration isn't possible, I can switch over to having the SSR take place in Nuxt rather than Django, but I'm curious to learn more about what sort of configuration issue is at play here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure vue router to use a different root URL.
Just replace in router.js

```
base: process.env.BASE_URL,
```

With

```
base: '/',
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an effect on the build. It still requests for `/js/` instead of `/static/js`

Answer (score 0):

I believe is resolved by adding

```
mode: "history",
```

to your router.js file.